# NetBeans waiting for connection - netstat shows established

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I've read through absolutely tons of questions troubleshooting this symptom:
NetBeans shows "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"

I've followed every single step in this guide (though I'm using XAMPP not WAMP) http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue

But in my case, netstat is showing that a connection is established and nothing that I do seems to make any difference.

I run the project in NetBeans, usually nothing happens the first time, but when I press "Debug" the second time, it opens in Chrome.

`http://localhost/projectName/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`

Then NetBeans just sits there stuck on "Waiting for connection"

In **php.ini** I've got

```
zend_extension = C:/xampp/apache/modules/php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll
...
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

In **phpInfo.php** I can see

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

I've tried with remote_host set to both 127.0.0.1 and my local IP as well, both times I see a connection as expected:

```
C:>netstat -o -n -a | findstr :9000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11224
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         127.0.0.1:50108        ESTABLISHED     11224
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         127.0.0.1:50110        ESTABLISHED     11224
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50108        127.0.0.1:9000         ESTABLISHED     11224
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50110        127.0.0.1:9000         ESTABLISHED     3892
  TCP    [::]:9000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       11224

C:>netstat -o -n -a | findstr :9000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11224
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         127.0.0.1:50330        ESTABLISHED     11224
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50330        127.0.0.1:9000         ESTABLISHED     11224
  TCP    192.168.0.15:9000      192.168.0.15:50332     ESTABLISHED     11224
  TCP    192.168.0.15:50332     192.168.0.15:9000      ESTABLISHED     1804
  TCP    [::]:9000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       11224
```

These are the correct PIDs for NetBeans and Apache.

Both programs are allowed through Windows Firewall and I added rules to allow connection through port 9000 as well. Tried turning the firewall off just to be sure, didn't make a difference either.

I have no idea what I could possibly be missing here. It's been several hours of reading threads with the same hang but I haven't found any case like this.

Any thoughts on troubleshooting what NetBeans could be stuck on?

Comment: Collect Xdebug log -- it may give you some hints.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I am having the same issue (the status bar says "waiting for connection" and when I try to debug the project, the page never loads until I kill netbeans). I also see connection established in netstat.